# Как применить функцию merge чтобы столбцы не клонировались а заполнялись

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Код для примера приведен ниже, необходимо написать такой мердж, чтобы значения столбцов value (таких столбцов на реальных данных будет много) не дублировалось в результате. То есть не было в итоговой таблице value_x, value_y, а были только value,  value2 и value3.

```
   df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
                'value': [1, 1, 1],
               'value2': [1, 2, 3]})
   df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                'value': [1, 1, 1, 1],
               'value3': [1, 2, 3,4]})
   df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='key')
```

Comment: что было понятнее чего вы хотите, приведите пример того как должна выглядеть окончательная таблица для приведенных входных данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если в результирующей таблице не нужны значения `values` из `df1` то можно просто из дропнуть перед тем как делать `merge`, примерно так:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
               'value': [1, 1, 1],
               'value2': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'fiz'],
               'value': [1, 1, 1, 1],
               'value3': [1, 2, 3,4]})

df3 = df2.merge(df1.drop(columns='value'), how='outer', on='key')
```

вывод:

```
   key  value  value3  value2
0  foo      1       1     1.0
1  bar      1       2     2.0
2  baz      1       3     3.0
3  fiz      1       4     NaN
```

Comment: Собственно да, если объединение по другим колонкам идёт, то и правда логичнее лишнюю колонку дропнуть до мержа, меньше мороки :)

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, как это делается оптимально, но можно оставить одну колонку без суффикса, а другую потом просто удалить:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='key', suffixes=(None,'_del')).drop(columns='value_del')
df3
```

Вывод:

```
    key value   value2  value3
0   foo     1        1       1
1   foo     1        1       4
2   bar     1        2       2
3   baz     1        3       3
```